# Highlighting the text when editing an item from the dhtmlx tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

When I want the user to rename an item from the tree, I open the editor for him:

```
 tree.editItem(tree.getSelectedItemId());
```

But I want the text in the editor to be selected (highlighted). Now the cursor is in the end of the text and the text isn't selected. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
document.getElementById('id').select();
```

here is working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aV4Er/)

Comment: Open jsfiddle on different browsers and test. You will find out. I havent tested it.

Comment: @Srcee: Which version of mozilla you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [**.select()**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqgMN/) to achieve this.

> [**.select()**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqgMN/) Bind an event handler to the "select" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

**Example:**

```
$('#txt').select();​
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wqgMN/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next:

```
tree.attachEvent("onEdit",function(state,id,tree,value){
    if(state==1){
        var inp = this._editCell.span.firstChild;
        inp.select();
    }
    if (state == 2){
        if (value == "" || value == " "){
            alert('Please, type the name of item');
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
})
```